# Windows 10 ISO download possible?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to get the Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft without installing it? If so, how? I do wish to benefit from the current free upgrade possibility but do am not able to perform the update at the current time, because of lack of free HDD space.

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser not stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, you can download ISOs [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).

Comment: It could be downloaded via agent substitution in dev tools (you should change it to chrome-ipad), there is an article: https://www.minitool.com/news/windows-10-iso-images-direct-download-via-microsoft.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) looks like it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the update tool download the data, in this case Windows 10 at first, and you may install it at a later time. Perhaps it is worth to taking a look at the Microsoft support page.